# React - Read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, filter

I am having a problem because I have a read properties of undefined (reading 'type') error that I cannot resolve. I receive the data from my API but the value of 'type' and undefined and I don't understand why? Someone would have any idea ?

```
export function picture(object) {
  const result = {
    type: 'photo',
    title: object.title,
    photoURL: object.url,
    owner: object.author_name,
    uploadDate: object.upload_date,
    html: object.html,
  };
  return result;
}
export function video(object) {
  const result = {
    type: 'video',
    title: object.title,
    uploadDate: object.upload_date,
    photoURL: object.thumbnail_url,
    owner: object.author_name,
    html: object.html,
    duration: object.duration,
  };
  return result;
}

export function filterData(object) {
  console.log(object);
  if (object.type === 'video') {
    return video(object);
  } else if (object.type === 'photo') {
    return picture(object);
  }
}
```

[console.log(object)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdSoO.png)

[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOfVn.png)

Comment: You are passing `result.msg` to `filterData`, but according to the log, the result object does not contain a `msg` property.  As a result, you are passing the value `undefined`, which is not an object (and thus can't have a property `type`).  Hence the error (attempt to read property `type` on `undefined`).

Comment: Thanks Dave. Indeed, I don't know why I put msg. Everything went back to normal once removed.